# React: How to link a checkbox with an input date field?

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in React and following is my problem:

I have a **Date** field and an **Expired** checkbox field next to it. When the user checks the **Expired** checkbox, the date field should be disabled. The state should then record *true* if the user checks the **Expired** field rather than the date.

I can keep those two fields separate. But I do not know (a) how to diable the date field when checkbox is checked and (b) Record the state as *true* in place of a date variable when checkbox is checked.

Inside the render, I have the following code (using Bootstrap):

```js
<div className="row m-1">
  <div className="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 pl-2">
    <label htmlFor="ExampleFormControlInput m-1">
      Date
    </label>
  </div>

  <div className="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 pl-1">
    <input
      className="form-control form-control-sm"
      type="date"
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
      min={moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
      onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, "lst_dt")}
      value={this.state.userData.validity}
    /></div>

  <div className="col-xs-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 mt-1">
    <label htmlFor="ExampleFormControlInput m-1">
      Expired
    </label>
  </div>

  <div className="col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 ">
    <input
      className="form-control form-control-sm"
      type="checkbox"
      style={{ width: "auto" }}
      onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, "expiry")}
      value={this.state.userData.expired}
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

In extends Component part of the code, I have the following:

```
state = {
  userData: {
    lst_dt: "",
    expiry: false,
  },
  error: false,
};
```

In handleInput, I have the following:

```js
handleInputChange = (e, name) => {
  let value = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;
  this.setState({
    userData: { ...this.state.userData, [name]: value },
  });
};
```

In FormReset, I have the following:

```
handleFormReset = () => {
  this.setState({
    userData: {
      validity: "",
      expired: false,
    },
    error: false,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the date field -

```html
<input type="date" disabled={this.state.userData.expired}/>
```

To Record the state as true in place of a date variable when checkbox is checked -

```js
handleInputChange = (e, name) => {
  let value = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked :
    e.target.value;
  this.setState({
    userData: { ...this.state.userData, [name]: value },
  });
  if (e.target.type === 'checkbox' && e.target.value) {
    this.setState({
      userData: { ...this.state.userData, validity: true },
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding disabled={!this.state.userData.expiry} in your date input like :

```html
<input
  className="form-control form-control-sm"
  type="date"
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
  min={moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
  onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, "lst_dt")}
  value={this.state.userData.validity}
  disabled={!this.state.userData.expiry}
/>
```